# is there any context.Database.Log in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In entity framework you can direct sql out on debug with this command

```
context.Database.Log = sql => Debug.WriteLine(sql);
```

But I cannot find any .Net core alternative. Does anyone know how this is achieved in .Net core?

Comment: Here is the "official" way of doing it - [Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging).

Answer (score 2):

I found solution [here](https://gist.github.com/tonysneed/4cac4f4dae2b22e45ec4):

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static void LogToConsole(this DbContext context)
    {
        var contextServices = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>) context).Instance;
        var loggerFactory = contextServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Verbose);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it crashed my studio but I think that may be due to my 1.4 framework. I'll mark it as answer once I get it to work.